# Show a warning if characters are more then 160 in a string

Tags: php

I want to implement a post update system like twitter where users can update their status in 160 charecters. I want to add some restrictions like If a user entered characters more then 160 ,then the **update_post.php** file must show him/her a warning and the extra characters(+160) inside HTML del tag. **Bellow is my code that I have tried so far. but it outputs nothing!**Any help is much appriciated! thanks

**sample_update.php**

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"method="post">
   <textarea name="msg"></textarea>
   <input type="submit"value="Post">
</form>

<?php
  if(strlen($txt)>160) {
      echo "Your post couldn't be submitted as it contains more then 160 chrecters!";
      $txt=$_POST['msg'];
      $checking=substr($txt,160);
      echo "<del style='color:red;'>$checking</del>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Are you receiving any error messages/notices? If not. I'd suggest turning on Error reporting & Formatting your code to something a little more readable

Comment: Do you have more than that in your PHP or is that all? Where are you filling the `$txt` variable? Have you tried just outputting the  `$txt` variable?

Comment: Do you really need this char length restriction done with php only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$txt` is set inside of your `if` statement you need to move it outside

```
$txt=$_POST['msg'];

if(strlen($txt)>160)
{
     echo "Your post couldn't be submitted as it contains more then 160 chrecters!";
     $checking=substr($txt,160);
     echo "<del style='color:red;'>$checking</del>";
}
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index 'msg'

Comment: @AmitThakur BTW: Nobody else noticed that `$_SERVER['SELF']` doesn't even exists!

Answer (score 2):

You should be getting notices about an undefined variable. This being `$txt` as from what I/we can see, `$txt` is defined inside your if loop. I have modified your code to be minimal lines but just as effective.

```
if (isset($_POST['msg'])){
    if (strlen($_POST['msg']) > 160){
        echo "Your post could not be submitted as it contains more than 160 characters!";
        echo "<del style='color:red;'>".substr($_POST['msg'],160)."</del>";
    }

}
```

I have also wrapped your $_POST around an `isset` statement, which will check if it's set before doing anything else.. If nothing is set, then the code will not execute and trigger some annoying error messages

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

(`$_SERVER['SELF']` doesn't exists only `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` Also you have to first assign the variable before you can check the length)

```
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"method="post">
    <textarea name="msg"></textarea>
    <input type="submit"value="Post">
</form>

<?php

    if(!empty($_POST['msg'])) {
        $txt = $_POST['msg'];

        if(strlen($txt) > 160) {
            echo "Your post couldn't be submitted as it contains more then 160 chrecters!";

            $checking = substr($txt,160);
            echo "<del style='color:red;'>$checking</del>";
        }
    } 



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` instead of `$_SERVER['SELF']`

You might want to move some of your conditions up, so you can use the check for something else. Furthermore, inserting the user typed text into the textarea is a good practice so the user dosnt have to retype the text again.

```php
<?php
    $maxlen = 160;
    $txt=(isset($_POST['msg'])) ? $_POST['msg'] : "";
    $check = strlen($txt) > $maxlen;
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
<textarea name="msg"><?php echo $txt; ?></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="post">
</form>
<?php
if ($check){
    echo "Your post couldn't be submitted as it contains more then $maxlen chrecters!";
    $checking = substr($txt,$maxlen);
    echo "<del style='color:red;'>$checking</del>";
} else {
    echo "You are good to go ma man - do something";
}
?>
```